# Run a hook in one plugin out of many, in Pluggy

Tags: python, plugins

I'm using [Pluggy](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pluggy) and I would like to run a hook in one of the plugins.

Having this code:

```
import pluggy
import myspec
import impl1
import impl2

pm = pluggy.PluginManager("my-project-name")
pm.add_hookspecs(myspec)
pm.register(impl1, name="my_impl1")
pm.register(impl2, name="my_impl2")
```

How can I run a specific hook in "impl1" only?